# How do i create a stringified json in AWS API gateway mapping templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am able to successfully create maps using a combination of `$stageVariables` and `$input.json`. This allows me to setup nice objects that I can easily forward to my step functions.

On of the step function parameters requires that the `input` field be a JSON string. I have no idea how to create a stringify the map that I created. If I just set the map to the input value it looks something like:

```
{
     "input": { value1=1, value2=2 },
     "stateMachineArn": "arn:goes:here"
}
```

Is there a way to do this at all?